# Is it necessary to use flutter doctor after installing flutter on laptop? If yes, what are the steps for running flutter doctor in command prompt?

Tags: flutter-doctor

Is it necessary to use flutter doctor after installing flutter on laptop? If yes, what are the steps for running flutter doctor in command prompt?
In the tutorial it showed "run the following command to see if there are any platform dependencies you need to complete the setup:

C:\src\flutter>flutter doctor"

i tried running flutter doctor in command prompt but it showed "'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
What to do?